# What needs to be done in Contact Form 7 to send data to php?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

As far as sending data from Contact Form 7 to my php function, I'm confused about what needs to be done inside Contact Form 7. If I want to send values to php but do not want to send an email, how do I call the php file? The form seems to fuss over the mail portion being empty also.

I have the login.php file completed, but not sure how to call it since it's in the root of my child theme.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'sign_in_client' );

function sign_in_client( $client_login_form)
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

  // Get the post data and other post meta values.
if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

  // these variables are examples of other things you may want to pass to your custom handler
    $user_name = $submission->get_meta( 'client-username' );
    $user_password = $submission->get_meta( 'client-password' );
```

Comment: So wait, you're using Contact Form 7 to create a login form?

Comment: Yes. It can do that, right?